# Asp.Net MVC Antiforgery validation fails when non-null usernames differ...is that reasonable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, csrf, antiforgerytoken

My question is about the MVC Antiforgery system (described [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages)).

Consider a simple app which posts todos to /Todo/Create. The corresponding action method has the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute. Consider the following client workflow:

1. User A logs on and goes to the page to create a todo, but doesn't do it yet.
2. User B (physically on the same computer) opens a new tab in the same browser, logs out of User A's account, logs in as User B. The browser then gets User B's validation cookie.
3. Some time later, User A switches back to their original tab and hits 'create' on the todo they were making.

In this scenario, the Antiforgery verification will not pass because the form token was meant for User A, while the validation cookie is for User B.

I'm sure there are valid security reasons for this behavior (e.g. a script on another site that manages to login as malicious user so that the 'todo' data is posted to their account instead), but it doesn't stop the above scenario happening for my legitimate users sometimes.

My questions are:

- Is there a 'best practices' way to handle this scenario? Is it usually just a case of showing a custom error, telling them to reload the page and/or login again etc?
- Is there any way to know when the out-of-the-box MVC Antiforgery system runs into this error? It seems to only ever throw the same kind of Exception (`HttpAntiForgeryException`). Would I need to revert to using/modifying their source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways of handling it:

1. Use Javascript callback to the server before hitting a button to detect if the user is still logged in. If not - display him a message. It should be relatively easy to do this. But it requires one additional call, and little bit more time to execute your request.

One solution to avoid callbacks could be using html 5 localStorage (and you can support that on other browsers using modernizr, for example). It is shared between tabs. But I'm not sure if this approach is good. Additional research required.

2. Catch HttpAntiForgeryException on the server, check if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, display him a message.

Usually approach (1) is used. On banking websites they detect with JavaScript when you logged out in other browser tab.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted because you've presented two/three reasonable approaches to handling this. #2 probably won't work all that well for me because my app also supports anonymous posts, but your answer has given me enough to think about. Maybe I'll just redirect to the login page in all cases, showing a generic message that covers all cases (something like "For security reasons we need you to login again (if this persists, please check you have cookies enabled, no other tabs open, and that no other users are logged in at the same time etc.)"). Thanks again for your time :).

Comment: (one problem with that redirect approach though might be that a user's post data is lost and they have to retype all their 'todo' information again after logging in :( )

Comment: @sammy34 to avoid loosing information you can implement generic way of saving information for your controls. Just serialize all the controls on particular page to localStorage. If user comes to that page again - prompt to recover information from localStorage if it's there. It could be nice to implement "Undo" for this operation as well.